# Who to define a value for instances of T/F in an R function input

Tags: r, function, subset

Below, I expect the function to output `.25` for any `long = T` and `.5` for any `long = F`. So, I expected to get a vector of `.25, .25, .25, .5, .25` as the `foo()` output.

I'm wondering how I could achieve my desired out put?

```
foo <- function(long = c(T, T, T, F, T)){

 r <- if(long)long[long] <- .25 else long[!long] <- .5
 r
 }
 ## Example of use:
foo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if/else` expects a vector of length 1 and gives back a logical `vector` of length 1.  We can use `ifelse`

```
foo <- function(long = c(T, T, T, F, T)){

   ifelse(long, .25, .5)

  }

foo()
```